# How to separate NestJS module and combine them?

Tags: nestjs

Here is the code what I have.

1. Main domain module

```
@Module({
    imports: [KeyInfraModule, KeyServiceModule]
})
export class KeyModule {}
```

2. Part of Infra module

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TerminusModule,
        ConfigModule.forRoot({envFilePath: "src/core/key/.key.env"}),
        RedisModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'single',
                url: configService.get<string>('REDIS_URL'),
                options: {}
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
            imports: [ConfigModule]
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                uri: configService.get('MONGO_URL'),
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        })
    ]
})
export class KeyInfraModule {}
```

3. Part of Service module that combine controller and provider

```
@Module({
    controllers: [KeyController],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: 'IKeyService',
            useClass: KeyService
        },
        {
            provide: 'IKeyRepo',
            useClass: KeyRepo
        }
    ],
    exports: [KeyServiceModule]
})
export class KeyServiceModule {}
```

I want to make modules like that structure.
But, that's not working because KeyServiceModule can't find KeyInfraModule's Services like ConfigService... etc.

`Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the KeyService (IKeyRepo, ?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [1] is available in the KeyServiceModule context.`

I want to split KeyModule with infra options and business logic options.

There are any way to make structure like that?

I try to write down exports options.
But, that's not working well.